# Hanson-wright inequality vs subexponential bound

Tags: probability, inequality

The Hanson-wright inequality is given by: for all $t>0$:

$$P(X^\intercal A X - E[X^\intercal A X ] \geq t) \leq \exp \Big[ -c \min \left(\frac{t^2}{K^4 \|A\|_F^2}, \frac{t}{K^2 \|A\|_2}\right)\Big]$$

where $X$ is a vector of independent subgaussian random variables with Orlicz norm $K$, $c$ is a universal positive constant and $A$ is a square matrix.

There are many proofs of this inequality, but one involves a decoupling argument: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.2872.pdf which I would argue is relatively complex.

Here is my proof of a similar bound:

$$X^\intercal A X - E[X^\intercal A X ] = \sum_i a_{ii}(X_i^2 - EX_i^2) + \sum_{i\neq j} a_{ij}X_iX_j$$

The first sum is subexponential and is easy to bound via a chernoff bound:

$$\mathbb P\left (\sum_i a_{ii}(X_i^2 - EX_i^2) \geq t\right) \leq \exp\left(-c \min \left\{\frac{t^2}{K^4\|A_{\text{diag}}\|^2_F}, \frac{t}{K^2\|A_{\text{diag}}\|_\infty}\right\}\right)$$

where $A_{\text{diag}}$ is equal to $A$ along the main diagonal, but $0$ in all other entries.

Similarly, the second sum can be shown to be subexponential with parameters $\sum_{i\neq j}4a_{ij}^2K^4$ and  $\min_{i\neq j}1/{\sqrt 2 a_{ij}K^2}$ so the Chernoff bound gives us:

$$\mathbb P \left ( \sum_{i\neq j} a_{ij} (X_iX_j - \mathbb EX_iX_j) \right )
\leq \exp\left (- \min \left \{ \frac{t^2}{8\|A-A_{\text{diag}}\|^2_FK^4}, \frac{t}{2\sqrt 2 \|A-A_{\text{diag}}\|_\infty K^2}\right \} \right )$$

Putting these two bounds together we can achieve the same rate as in the Hanson-wright inequality.

My question: why is such a technical method taken to prove the Hanson-wright inequality if a more standard approach achieves the same rates? Is it really just for the constant factor of $\|A\|_2$ sometimes being better than the constant factor $\|A\|_\infty$? Otherwise, the two bounds are the same.

EDIT: to clarify a point in the comments below:

For two subexponential variables $X_1, X_2$ with parameters $(\nu_1, \alpha_1), (\nu_2, \alpha_2)$ the sum is subexponential with parameter $(\sqrt{2(\nu_1^2 + \nu_2^2)}, \max \{\alpha_1, \alpha_2\})$ because:

$$\mathbb E e^{\lambda (X_1 + X_2)} \leq \sqrt{\mathbb E e^{2\lambda X_1}\mathbb E e^{2\lambda X_1}} = e^{2\lambda^2 (\nu_1^2 + \nu_2^2)/2}$$

where the inequality follows by Cauchy schwarz, even for dependent rvs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for decoupling is because $X_iX_j$'s in the second sum are not independent. Therefore, instead of $\sqrt{\sum_{i\neq j}a_{ij}^2}K^2$, the parameter is bounded by $\sqrt{(\sum_{i\neq j}a_{ij})^2}K^2$. It is easy to see how different these are by taking $a_{ij}=a$(constant). While the former is about $naK^2$, the latter is about $n^2aK^2$. Thus you can see the latter cannot be bounded by the former with an absolute constant.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the case. $X_iX_j$ is subexponential with parameter $\sqrt{K^4}$, so $a_{ij}X_iX_j$ is subexponential with parameter $\sqrt{a_{ij}^2K^4}$. Then the sum has parameter bounded by $\sqrt{2\sum a_{ij}^2K^4}$. This last step follows from cauchy schwarz and the definition of the MGF.

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to by "follows from cauchy schwarz and the definition of the MGF". It might make things clear if you elaborate it in your post.

Comment: Sorry about that, I gave some clarification in the main post (at the end)

Comment: Thanks for adding it. If you repeat what you obtained for two variables repeatedly, "2" will pile up. How can you avoid "2"'s to pile up?

Comment: That's a big oversight on my part, thank you!